# How to send APIKey in Auth header in fetch request in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, post, authorization, api-authorization

I am trying to send post request to a url on which authorization of type **API Key** is enabled. I am able to send request through the post man. The API is responding perfectly fine, but when I come to fetch in Vuejs. I am unable to send the POST request using fetch.
Screenshot of POSTMAN is attached.
[image]

The tried code which I am using in Vuejs is:-

```
const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-Key":"3C68F15FF89132BF254E5FB648FCA",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.name,
        phonenumber: this.phoneNumber,
        msg: this.message,
      }),
    };
    let response = await fetch(
      "https://auto.toxiclabs.net/webhook/d6121492-4b9c-4dc2-908f-991001b20b61",
      requestOptions
    );
```

The error I am getting
[image]

Anyone who can tell me what actually is wrong in my code ?

Comment: I see CORS issues. Maybe Access-Control-Allow-Headers should be set for the API server?

I see `simlessform` as the key name in POSTMAN and I see `X-API-Key` as the key name in requestOptions